# Access dictionary property with dollar sign `$` in it's name using django template syntax in Klaviyo

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates, properties

I'm trying to access a property with a `$` in its name in a django template. Unfortunately I have no control over filters nor over the variable names.

The object is structured as follows:

```json
{
    "title": "Some title",
    "metadata": {
        "$price": 9.99,
        "$inventory_policy": 1
    }
}
```

I am trying to access `{{ item.metatadata.$price }}`, but the template builder crashes with an unspecified error.

I already tried the workarounds for python templates, but they crash as well:

```py
{{ item.metatadata.$$price }}
{{ item.metatadata.${price} }}
```

For future reference, this is in a Klaviyo template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. They supply an undocumented `lookup` filter for exactly that reason. It probably looks exactly like in [Lucas Grugru's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73727784/5249411) answer.

```
{{ item.metatadata|lookup:"$price" }}
```

The relevant section in the Klaviyo documentation is https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005084927-Guide-to-Template-Tags-and-Variable-Syntax#event-variables-4, where the `lookup` filter is used in an unrelated example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a custom filter for doing that : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

in templatetags.extras.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_value(dictio, key):
   return dictio.get(key, '')
```

and for using it:

```
{% load extras %}
{{ item.metatadata|get_value:"$price" }}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this is on a closed proprietary system (Klaviyo) and I do not have acces to the filters. It is beyond me why they would use `$` in their variable names if they use django templates, but it is what it is.

Comment: I do not know Klaviyo. What can you change  ? only the html code template ? In this case, i think it will be very hard to find a solution.

Comment: I see you are find a solution. Good !